Deploying contract through create2 is returning a zero address
In this function I am deploying a contract through create2 and in this NFTImplementation is just a standard ERC721 implementation. The function always reverts due to the address returned from the create2 being a zero address which indicates there was a error deploying the contract.
function _createWrappedToken(uint16 tokenChainId, address tokenAddress, bytes32 name, bytes32 symbol) public returns (address token) {
        require(tokenChainId != getChainId(), "createWrappedToken: can only wrap tokens from foreign chains");
        require(getWrappedNFTContract(tokenChainId, tokenAddress) == address(0), "createWrappedToken: wrapped asset already exists");


        // initialize the NFTImplementation
        bytes memory initialisationArgs = abi.encodeWithSelector(
            NFTImplementation.initialize.selector,
            "Z-Coin",
            "ZZZ",

            address(this),

            tokenChainId,
            tokenAddress
        );

        // initialize the BeaconProxy constructor
        bytes memory constructorArgs = abi.encode(address(this), initialisationArgs);

        // bytecode to deploy
        bytes memory bytecode = abi.encodePacked(type(WrappedNFT).creationCode, constructorArgs);

        bytes32 salt = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(tokenChainId, tokenAddress));

        // deploy wrapped token contract
        assembly {
            token := create2(0, add(bytecode, 0x20), mload(bytecode), salt)

            if iszero(extcodesize(token)) {
                revert(0, 0)
            }
        }

        setWrappedNFTContracts(tokenChainId, tokenAddress, token);
    }

This is how I'm calling this function in test file:
nftBridgeProxy._createWrappedToken(2, address(nftImpl), "Z Coin", "ZZZ");


It turns out the error was in this:
bytes memory constructorArgs = abi.encode(address(this), initialisationArgs);

This acts as the constructor for a contract (WrappedNFT) which implements OpenZeppelin's BeaconProxy. So the first argument should be an address of a contract that contains implementation() function that returns the address of the contract to which the initialisationArgs needs to be called on.
